# How to configure AppArmor to deny disk access (real /etc/), while allowing container image access (virtual /etc)

Tags: apparmor

I would like to allow a container to write to its own virtual disk (/etc), but prevent it from accessing the real disk (/etc). I believe this is possible with SELinux by using labels, but is it also possible with AppArmor? I haven't found any online examples of this.

**Reproducible example:**

```
cat > /etc/apparmor.d/containers/docker-empty <<EOF
#include <tunables/global>

profile docker-empty flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  file,
  deny /etc/** wl,

  capability chown,
  capability dac_override,
  capability setuid,
  capability setgid,
  capability net_bind_service,
}
EOF

apparmor_parser -r -W /etc/apparmor.d/containers/docker-empty

# docker ignores apparmor setting, so podman must be used

# pass (should pass)
podman run --security-opt "apparmor=docker-empty" --rm -it debian:12 touch /test

# fail (should pass)
podman run --security-opt "apparmor=docker-empty" --rm -it debian:12 touch /etc/test

# pass (should fail)
podman run --security-opt "apparmor=docker-empty" --rm -it -v /:/realroot debian:12 touch /realroot/test

# pass (should fail)
podman run --security-opt "apparmor=docker-empty" --rm -it -v /:/realroot debian:12 touch /realroot/etc/test
```

The last one is especially annoying, because the AppArmor profile prevents access to the virtual `/etc`, but doesn't block access to the real `/etc` since it is mounted in a different path, `/realroot/etc`.